# call to undefined function ejabberd_logger:info_msg

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I was trying to log chat messages to mysql in **Ejabberd 14.07** using **mod_log_chat_mysql5** in Ubuntu.

Ejabberd is already configured in such a way to store basic details in Mysql. That feature is working and I am able to see newly registered users, offline messages etc in Mysql DB.

When mod_log_chat_mysql5 is enabled, Ejabberd is starting but following error message is logged and chat tables are not populated. Please help ....

> [error] <0.433.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.433.0> with 0 neighbours
>   exited with reason: call to undefined function
>   ejabberd_logger:info_msg(mod_log_chat_mysql5, 62, "Starting ~p",
>   [mod_log_chat_mysql5]) in gen_server:init_it/6 line 328

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you call `ejabberd_logger:info_msg/4` which is not defined.

Have a look to your versions, it seem that in the past the include file ejabberd.hrl defined the macro:

```
-define(INFO_MSG(Format, Args),
    ejabberd_logger:info_msg(?MODULE,?LINE,Format, Args)).
```

it is no more the case in 14.07. The macro is now defined in logger.hrl and is expanded to

```
lager:info(Format, Args))
```

or

```
p1_logger:info_msg(?MODULE, ?LINE, Format, Args))
```

depending on the flag `LAGER`